# Python program for converting list into dictionary not working properly

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def dic_index(n):
    i = 0
    words = {}
    while i<lines:
        for word in n[i]:
            print word
            if duplicate(word, words, i+1)==True:
                break
            elif word in words:
                words[word].append(i+1)
            else:
                words[word]=[i+1]
        i+=1
    return words
```

This is my function for converting a list into a dictionary in python.

For some reason when if enter this as the parameter:

```
[['brisk', 'blow', 'wind', 'blow'], ['north', 'north', 'youth'], ['wind', 'cold', 'cold'], ['wind', 'yesteryear'], []]
```

It returns a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'blow': [1], 'north': [2], 'brisk': [1], 'cold': [3], 'yesteryear': [4], 'wind': [1, 3, 4]}
```

For some reason it seem to be skipping the 'youth' entry in in the 2nd list in the parameter, and I don't have a clue why it is doing that.

For some reason the for loop seems to be skipping over that word.

This is my definition of duplicate:

```
def duplicate(word, dic, line):
    if word not in dic:
        return False
    values = dic[word]
    length = len(values)
    if values[length-1] == line:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The goal of my program is to take input from the user clear out all stop words etc.
and print a out a index. Each list in the list that is my example parameter represents a separate line. So in this case the "lines" variable in my dic_index() function would be 4.

Comment: Where do `lines` and `x` come from?

Comment: What is the definition of `duplicate()`?

Comment: Don't make it a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), explain the actually problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Your code creates an infinite loop; you never increment `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused `break` with `pass`?

Try:

```
    if duplicate(word, words, i+1)==True:
        pass
```

[edit - explaining] If you use "break", then the `for` loop will break at the first duplicate, and everything that remains on that list will be ignored. So in ["north", "north", "youth"] the first "north" is ok, the second "north" triggers the break, and the loop doesn't even reach "youth".
If you use "pass" on the other hand, the second "north" is ignored and you go to the i+=1 line.

NOTE:
I had to fix your program by replacing all `x` with `i` and `length` with `len(n)`.

Comment: oh, right - `pass` won't give trouble in this specific piece of code, but you should use `continue` as @MartijnPieters correctly wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `break` to end the per-line loop, skipping any words following a duplicated word in a line. You probably wanted to use `continue` instead. Your code is needlessly complicated, however.

Use `enumerate()` to number the lines, and `collections.defaultdict` for ease, and a `set()` to track words already counted:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dic_index(lines):
    indices = defaultdict(list)

    for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        seen = set()
        for word in line:
            if word in seen:
                continue
            seen.add(word)
            indices[word].append(i)

    return indices
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sample = [['brisk', 'blow', 'wind', 'blow'], ['north', 'north', 'youth'], ['wind', 'cold', 'cold'], ['wind', 'yesteryear'], []]
>>> def dic_index(lines):
...     indices = defaultdict(list)
...     for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
...         seen = set()
...         for word in line:
...             if word in seen:
...                 continue
...             seen.add(word)
...             indices[word].append(i)
...     return indices
... 
>>> dic_index(sample)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blow': [1], 'north': [2], 'brisk': [1], 'youth': [2], 'cold': [3], 'yesteryear': [4], 'wind': [1, 3, 4]})
```

Comment: Every time I post an answer and you post yours, I feel like you're my personal Python trainer. Thanks :p